# Avoid leaking internal function information: How to correctly detect and strip symbols in Windows dll files?

Tags: c++, windows, rust, dll

I have a `.dll` file containing some algorithms and I do not want to leak the implementations about that algorithm. Originally I thought was safe, since in Windows the debug info is in `.pdb`. However, I tried to use `dumpbin.exe /ALL myfile.dll`, and see tons of *my internal function names* there, making the attacker's life much easier since he can know the name of each function. It is like:

```
Function Table (24926)

           Begin    End      Info      Function Name
...

  00001158 000xxxx0 0xxxx277 008AD830  _ZN4core3ptr102drop_in_place$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$vision_utils_rs..algo..rep..row_detect..core_algo..TextRow$GT$$GT$17h0axxxfa922f149aE.llvm.176520069xxxxxx41370
    Unwind version: 1
    Unwind flags: None
    Size of prologue: 0x0E
    Count of codes: 7
    Unwind codes:
      0E: SAVE_XMM128, register=xmm6 offset=0x20
      09: ALLOC_SMALL, size=0x38
      05: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rbx
      04: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rdi
      03: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rsi
      02: PUSH_NONVOL, register=r14
```

which is a function in the core algorithm (`core_algo` folder of my code).

Therefore, I wonder:

1. How can I remove this function name? The programs using this `.dll` *never* call such a `_ZN4core3ptr102drop_in_place$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$vision_utils_rs..algo..rep..row_detect..core_algo..TextRow$GT$$GT$17h0axxxfa922f149aE.llvm.176520069xxxxxx41370` function, so removing this function name should be safe.
2. What else should I do? If I look at `dumpbin.exe /ALL myfile.dll` and do not see any text containing `core_algo` (the core algorithm folder of my code), am I safe? Or am I still missing something?

P.S. If you are interested, the DLL is compiled from Rust code; but C++ code should have similar effects. The `Cargo.toml` is:

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

In other words, I do a release build (`cargo build --release`) but keep the debug information (since I want to upload debug info to Sentry for symbolication). But I want a further stripping to remove before giving to end user.

Comment: *since in Windows the debug info is in .pdb* -- The .pdb is not a "Windows" thing.  It only exists for languages built with the Microsoft compiler/linker suite.

Comment: Why is this tagged c/c++?

Answer (score 5):

If someone is determined to reverse engineer your program, **they will**, and there is nothing you can do to stop them.  If you take all the symbols out they will still analyze the machine code.  If you obfuscate the machine code they will reverse engineer *that*.

The vast majority of people, on the other hand, *do not care* how your program works, and will not even notice whether the binary has symbols.

Therefore, any effort put into hardening your program against reverse engineering is wasted effort.  Don't worry about it.  Concentrate on making the program better at what it actually does, so that people *want* to give you money for it.

---

**EDIT:** Responding to [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy)'s comment from last year:

> This is not to say *some* hardening is unwarranted... You just want to raise the bar enough to deter the casual kiddies who think they're l33t hackz0rs.

I disagree with this. IMNSHO **all** effort put into hardening against reverse engineering is wasted effort.  In particular, "stripping out" symbols (function and object names) from a compiled binary is not only wasted effort, it is **counterproductive**.  It makes people who are motivated by curiosity less likely to be satisfied by a casual glance through the symbol table. At the same time, it makes it harder for your users to send you good bug reports.

In this context it's worth pointing out that Microsoft themselves, despite zealously protecting their "intellectual property" interest in Windows, make [detailed symbol tables and other debugging information for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/microsoft-public-symbols) available to the general public. That service costs them money to run, and it makes it *easier* for the developers of [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) and [ReactOS](https://reactos.org/) to figure out what they need to do to be bug-compatible with Windows.  They run it anyway, because they understand that it's even more valuable for them to facilitate debugging weird application crashes that involve core Windows components somehow.

---

Footnote: "Hardening against reverse engineering" should not be confused with "hardening against security exploits".  Stack canaries, control flow integrity protection, etc. *are* worth doing.

Comment: This is so spot-on.  Great answer!  The attackers usually have more time and resources than any practical resistance effort, and they generally have more expertise too.  This is not to say _some_ hardening is unwarranted...  You just want to raise the bar enough to deter the casual kiddies who think they're l33t hackz0rs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I agree with @paddy - at least strip out the symbols such that it is not *that* easy to be reverse engineered.

Comment: So, could you please provide some hints about how to remove those symbols mentioned in the question? Thanks

Comment: @ch271828n You will need to look at the various linker flags that are used to build the final executable and experiment with them   If none of them "work", then you're stuck.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But I hope there is something like `strip` in linux

Comment: Stripping out this symbol will achieve precisely nothing

Comment: There is no equivalent to `strip` on Windows. This is not an oversight; the problem that `strip` solves (in this case anyway) is one that standard Windows build tools never run into. The result of picking the right defaults: Debug information is collected into separate artifacts, so it doesn't have to retro-actively be stripped from the binary. Plus, all symbols are private by default, so the linker won't have to retro-actively decide, based on circumstantial evidence.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer: The DLL is indeed without such information. It is because of a PDB that is hidden somewhere else and I did not realize. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71422958/4619958 for the full details.