# What is "Function Table" provided by dumpbin, and how to manipulate it?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, rust, dll

I use `dumpbin.exe /ALL myfile.dll` and see something interesting:

```
Function Table (24926)

           Begin    End      Info      Function Name
...

  00001158 000xxxx0 0xxxx277 008AD830  _ZN4core3ptr102drop_in_place$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$vision_utils_rs..algo..rep..row_detect..core_algo..TextRow$GT$$GT$17h0axxxfa922f149aE.llvm.176520069xxxxxx41370
    Unwind version: 1
    Unwind flags: None
    Size of prologue: 0x0E
    Count of codes: 7
    Unwind codes:
      0E: SAVE_XMM128, register=xmm6 offset=0x20
      09: ALLOC_SMALL, size=0x38
      05: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rbx
      04: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rdi
      03: PUSH_NONVOL, register=rsi
      02: PUSH_NONVOL, register=r14
```

I wonder:

1. How to remove this `Function Name` from the `.dll` file?
2. How to print this section separately (instead of using `/all` flag)? I have look through all flags of `dumpbin` without success.

Thanks for any hints!

Related to: [Avoid leaking internal function information: How to correctly detect and strip symbols in Windows dll files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71403623/avoid-leaking-internal-function-information-how-to-correctly-detect-and-strip-s) But rephrased since that question focuses on security, while this question asks about *facts* that I want to learn.

---

**EDIT**

Experiment when the `pdb` file is deliberately renamed.

I deliberately renamed the pdb as follows:

[image]

Then execute dumpbin:

```
$DUMPBIN='C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\Hostx64\x64\dumpbin.exe'; $F='C:\Users\xxx\rust\target\release\vision_utils_rs.dll'

  00001158 000401B0 00040277 008AD830  _ZN4core3ptr102drop_in_place$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$vision_utils_rs..algo..rep..row_detect..core_algo..TextRow$GT$$GT$17h0a2856fa922f149aE.llvm.17652006900120541370
... and many more ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The word "unwind" is your clue that this is related to exceptions. 64-bit Windows uses table based [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-170). Unless you want to rewrite your code to not use exceptions nor object destructors, those tables have to stay.

The name of the function however is not required and should go away if there are no symbols and you already have an open question about that so I wont bother with that here.

The command is probably `dumpbin /unwindinfo` or `/pdata`.

Comment: "The name of the function however is not required and should go away if there are no symbols" - that open question does not have any answer for this yet. Could you please give some hints? Thank you!

Comment: @ch2 Unfortunately, Rust is squarely focused on how *NIX does things, and thus inherits all the good as well as bad from it. Among the bad is the fact, that symbols are public by default. If you need to strip symbols you're going to have to explicitly opt-in to sanity by specifying the [`strip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#strip) option (either `strip = "symbols"` or `strip = true` will do).

Comment: @IInspectable Hi thanks for the reply! However, I want to upload a non-stripped version of the DLL to Sentry, such that I can symbolicate the stack traces later.

Comment: *Unless you want to rewrite your code to not use exceptions nor object destructors, those tables have to stay.* - even if code not use exceptions (handlers) and object destructors, this table (.pdata) anyway will be generated

Comment: @ch2 To get symbolic information for stack traces you don't need symbol information in the binary. Symbol information is generally provided by separate artifacts, usually the PDB. This is another case of inheriting the bad: By default, debug information is compiled into the binary. That's totally not where it belongs, and the designers of the Windows platform have figured this out decades ago.

Comment: Again, you have to explicitly request generation of symbol information for release configurations using the [`debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#debug) option, i.e. `debug = true` for `[profile.release]`. Fortunately, [`split-debuginfo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#split-debuginfo) defaults to `packed` when using the MSVC toolchain, so symbol information is compiled into a separate PDB file.

Comment: @RbMm When I tried it I believe the table had just a single entry (.exe without CRT). It would still run if you delete the pdata section and data directory but I don't know how safe that is.

Comment: How many not leaf functions have your exe ? I primary create executables without exceptions handlers, crt . And anyway my PE have .pdata with multiple entries. Not sure are possible of this with some cl/link options. This section of course possible cut without lost basic functional, but exceptions, etc stop work

Comment: @IInspectable Hi thanks for the reply! I do use `[profile.release]debug=true`, and the default split-debuginfo config. I tried to rename the `pdb` file to a dummy name such that the `dll` should not understand it. However, when using `dumpbin` I still see the names! Please see edited question for the whole experiment. Could you please provide some hints? Thanks!

Comment: @RbMm Anders Hi I accept having pdata, just want the *symbol name literals* to disappear.

Comment: @ch2 You'll also need the `strip` option.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, but imho `strip=none` (default) leads to my question. `strip=debuginfo/symbols` says "... are not copied to the produced binary or separate files". So the `.pdb` will not contain useful information. But I want to upload `pdb` to Sentry (or save a local copy) so I can symbolicate stack trace later.

Comment: I found the answer... (See my answer to this question) Thanks for your help all the same!

Comment: @ch2 Another case of being squarely focused on how *NIX does things: The documentation. It (apparently) applies to *NIX targets only. Specifying `strip = "symbols"` has **no** effect on the generated PDB when using the MSVC toolchain. Unfortunate, really. There are sane defaults, as used by the MSVC toolchain literally for decades. But Rust turns everything into a royal mess by defaulting to less-than-ideal.

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting... So `strip=symbols` has effects on dll? (So surprising: I *cannot* rely on official doc!)

Comment: @ch2 It turns out my observation was wrong. Cargo pulled the PDB from the *deps* directory, assigned a new timestamp, and led me to believe that `strip = "symbols"` had no effect on PDB generation. The documentation is correct; `strip` prevents generation of PDBs altogether. Not that that's a good thing, since there's no combination of options that produces PDBs while stripping all symbols from the executable image. Setting `debug = true` as well as `lto = true` gets you pretty close: Full PDBs and a mostly stripped binary; only CRT support library symbols remain.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: There is *another* pdb that this dll file is *really* pointing to.

As is described in the question, I have temporarily renamed the `vision_utils_rs.pdb` in the same folder as `vision_utils_rs.dll`, which are both output artifacts of Rust compilation. Then I thought I was safe and dll will not know about pdb.

However, when I wander around looking at `dumpbin /headers myfile.dll`, I see:

```
    622xxxB5 cv            7C 00xxxx84   8Axxx4    Format: RSDS, {3088D8E1-E258-xxxx-BB0F-70B67F466392}, 2, C:\xxx\target\release\deps\vision_utils_rs.pdb
```

Notice the extra `deps` folder. So, indeed, when examining the DLL, that `deps/vision_utils_rs.pdb` is *actually* what is used to show debug information. Once I rename that, everything is fine.

I am very unfamiliar with Windows systems so made such a silly mistake... Hope this answer helps future people who are facing the same problem!